# Which scope use maven when encountering custom scope?

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

In a recently Maven 2 project migrated to Maven 3, I have warnings (*scope must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is '...'*) due to use of custom scopes.

The custom scope in question is `package` and I could not find documentation/hint about which is the default when encountering invalid/custom scope.

1. Does the "package" custom scope ring anything to those still knowing maven 2? I could find references [here](http://www.developpez.net/forums/i346642/java/general-java/langage/signer-information-does-not-match-signer-information/) and [here](http://communitygrids.blogspot.fr/2005/12/using-maven-2-part-2.html) but that's almost all.
2. What is the default scope in that case? (I guess it is `compile`, but I'd like to be sure before changing anything).

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware that a [scope `package`](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dependency+Scopes) existed. The blogs entries are simply wrong. The default scope is `compile` and you can find the [documentation about the available scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

If you have a default like the scope you simply omit the entry from your dependency.

Older versions of Maven like 2.0.11, 2.2.1 do not check all entries in the pom file like the scope so it has been ignored since Maven 3 they are checked for valid values.

Comment: I know about this docs, but I can't find something explicit like "if you use a custom scope, it's wrong and it will be replaced by `compile`". By the way, I did not understand this: "*If you have a default like the scope you simply omit the entry from your dependency.*" ?

Comment: The default scope is `compile` which you can simply omit from the dependency.

Comment: Any concrete proof, apart from experience I mean ?

Comment: What do you mean? This is the default in XSD and of course documented (http://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

Comment: The docs says *this is the default scope, used if none is specified* but that is different from *this is the scope used if an unknown one is provided*. And I can't find a documentation about that :/ (even if, in the end, I will probably use the compile scope). Also, the maven patch that added this warning does not tell much: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3991